# Limit disk size and bandwidth of a Docker container

Tags: docker

I have a physical host machine with Ubuntu 14.04 running on it. It has 100G disk and 100M network bandwidth. I installed Docker and launched 10 containers. I would like to limit each container to a maximum of 10G disk and 10M network bandwidth.

After going though the official documents and searching on the Internet, I still can't find a way to allocate specified size disk and network bandwidth to a container.

I think this may not be possible in Docker directly, maybe we need to bypass Docker. Does this means we should use something "underlying", such as LXC or Cgroup? Can anyone give some suggestions?

---

Edit:

@Mbarthelemy, your suggestion seems to work but I still have some questions about disk:

1) Is it possible to allocate other size (such as 20G, 30G etc) to each container? You said it is hardcoded in Docker so it seems impossible.

2) I use the command below to start the Docker daemon and container:

```
docker -d -s devicemapper
docker run -i -t training/webapp /bin/bash
```

then I use `df -h` to view the disk usage, it gives the following output:

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-longid   9.8G  276M  9.0G   3% /
/dev/mapper/Chris--vg-root   27G  5.5G   20G  22% /etc/hosts
```

from the above I think the maximum disk a container can use is still larger than 10G, what do you think 
?

Answer (score 28):

I don't think this is possible right now using Docker default settings. Here's what I would try.

- About disk usage: You could tell Docker to use the DeviceMapper storage backend instead of AuFS. This way each container would run on a block device (Devicemapper dm-thin target) limited to 10GB (this is a Docker default, luckily enough it matches your requirement!).

  According to [this link](https://github.com/snitm/docker/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper/README.md), it looks like latest versions of Docker now accept advanced storage backend options. Using the `devicemapper`backend, **you can now change the default container rootfs size option using `--storage-opt dm.basesize=20G` (that would be applied to any newly created container)**.

  To change the storage backend: use the `--storage-driver=devicemapper` Docker option. Note that your previous containers won't be seen by Docker anymore after the change.
- About network bandwidth : you could tell Docker to use LXC under the hoods : use the `-e lxc`option.

  Then,  create your containers with a custom LXC directive to put them into a **traffic class** :

  `docker run --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.net_cls.classid = 0x00100001" your/image /bin/stuff`

  Check the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/net_cls.txt) about how to apply bandwidth limits to this class.
  I've never tried this myself (my setup uses a custom OpenVswitch bridge and VLANs for networking, so bandwidth limitation is different and somewhat easier), but I think you'll have to create and configure a different class.

Note : the `--storage-driver=devicemapper`and `-e lxc`options are for the Docker **daemon**, not for the Docker client you're using when running `docker run .......`.

Comment: mbarthelemy , I supplement my question about the disk , can you help to look into ?

Comment: Your root FS volume is the first one (`|9.8G |276M| 9.0G | 3% |/`). The size is, as expected, 10GB. The other line is a bind-mount.

Comment: your suggestion is a good  way to limit disk size . But I think there is another approach  to implement this . I decide to add another user to specified group  in container  , then I then limit the disk size of that group by using "Quota" in Linux.About the bandwidth , it is too complex for me ,I am still trying ,maybe will ask you something later.

Comment: @mbarthelemy could you please give me some details about how you make  OpenVswitch bridge and VLAN work with Docker? I'm very interested in Docker work with SDN. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried to use `docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G`, but it is not working, doesn't limit disc sapce.

Comment: official documentation was changed to `https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/net_cls.txt`

Answer (score 6):

New releases version has `--device-read-bps` and `--device-write-bps`.

**You can use:**

```
docker run --device-read-bps=/dev/sda:10mb
```

More info here:

https://blog.docker.com/2016/02/docker-1-10/

Comment: It should be noted that this is only for block devices.  Interface traffic hasn't been added.  [4763](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4763) is still open

Comment: Link is out of date

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the containers you can use tc for bandwidth control within them.

eg: in your entry point script you can add:
`tc qdisc add dev eth0 root tbf rate 240kbit burst 300kbit latency 50ms`

to have a bandwidth of 240kbps, burst 300kbps and 50 ms latency.

You also need to pass the `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` to the `docker run` command if you are not running the containers as root.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is it possible to allocate other size (such as 20G, 30G etc) to each container? You said it is hardcoded in Docker so it seems impossible.

to answer this question please refer to [Resizing Docker containers with the Device Mapper plugin](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/)