# Docker container disk size in mesos and marathon

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

Does Marathon impose a disk space resource limit on Docker container applications? By default, I know that Docker containers can grow as needed in their host VMs, but when I tried to have Marathon and Mesos create and manage my Docker containers, I found that the container would run out of space during installation of packages. As it stands, I cannot just cache the installation of these packages in a prebuilt image.

So if Marathon does impose a disk space resource limit, is there a way to turn that off?

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking about memory limits or disk space limits?

Comment: disk space. Just edited.

Answer (score 0):

Marathon should not impose a size limit on your containers, and as far as I am aware there are no limitations to the size of a container that Marathon can run, so long as the box you are running Marathon and the containers on top of have sufficient resources allocated (remaining).

That being said, there is a great response by user mbarthelemy at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24393016/5136426) where he goes into detail regarding devicemapper settings in Ubuntu that allow you to allocate disk size and network resources to each container on a docker level.

Answer (score 0):

No. Marathon does not enforce any resource limits itself, although your app definition can declare cpu/memory/disk limits. It is up to Mesos to actually enforce these limits. Mesos 0.22 added support for disk quota isolation, but it is not enabled by default (check the slave's `--isolators` flag), so I doubt that was your problem.

What is the slave's `--work_dir`? If it's mapping to `/tmp/mesos` (default), and that happens to be a tiny ramdisk/SSD, you might actually be running out of space on the host machine/VM.