# How do I predefine the maximum runtime disk space for Containers launched from a Docker image?

Tags: docker

With  `docker build`, how do I  specify the maximum disk space to be allocated to the runtime container?

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013904/how-to-limit-docker-filesystem-space-available-to-containers) mentioned *runtime constraints*, and I am aware of `--storage-opt`, but that concerns  *runtime parameters* on `dockerd` or `run docker` -- and in contrast, I want to specify the limit in advance, at *image build time*.

(Note that I am not talking about specifying the disk footprint  of the image, but rather about specifying the the maximum disk space for the *container*.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit Docker filesystem space available to container(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013904/how-to-limit-docker-filesystem-space-available-to-containers)

Comment: It is different -- see my edited text above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this at build time. A container's max disk space can be only limited at runtime.

Now, if you are concerned that your disk might get full due to Docker stuff (images, logs, etc), what you can do is mount `/var/lib/docker` in a partition different than the main system partition, this way you know that getting out of space in docker won't crash your system. Or in case of Docker for Mac, you have a disk limit in the preferences.